# How to use glew with XCode

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, xcode5, glew

I am trying to use glew 1.10.0 with the latest XCode(5.0.2) an the latest Mac OsX version. So far, I have tried different things:

- Added the library "libGLEW.1.10.0.dylib" in the Build Phases tab
- Added the OpenGL Framework in the Build Phases tab
- Changed the Header search path to "usr/local/Cellar/glew/1.10.0/include"
- Changed the Library search path to "usr/local/Cellar/glew/1.10.0/lib"
- Included GL/glew.h with "<>" and ""

I am always getting the error "'GL/glew.h' file not found"

Answer (score 5):

Since there is a single library you link to whether you get the legacy OpenGL 2.1 renderer or a core 3.2+ renderer, GLEW is completely unnecessary on OS X. This means that things from OpenGL 3.2+ will resolve at link-time (before you even have a render context to check whether it is supported or not). If you try to use functions that are not implemented by your renderer at run-time however, you will either get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error or the operation will silently fail. It is a difference between link-time (OS X) and run-time (Windows, Linux, etc.) resolution of GL functions.

Just include `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` if you are going to use functionality from OpenGL 3.2+ core on OS X and forget about GLEW. The set of implemented extensions across all hardware OS X officially supports is relatively homogeneous depending more on the renderer version than the actual hardware vendor (Apple writes all of the drivers). You should refer to [this matrix](https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/) that Apple publishes for more details on GL capabilities, rather than relying on GLEW.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the link, it's quite useful. I will use some preprocessor statements to include and use glew when I'm on Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the glew include files to the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` located in the project settings, then you will be able to compile.

But be aware that GLEW is completelly unnecessary on OSX. OSX already comes with OpenGL and all the extensions for the "modern OpenGL" already prepared to be used. You really don't need GLEW for anything.

Comment: I have already added the include path in XCode like I said in my post, but it won't compile. The reason why I want to use glew is, because I want to have a cross plattform software in the end.

Comment: I see... anyways... use #ifdef's to setup GLEW under Windows and/or Linux... but when you be at __APPLE__, just use Apple OpenGL's headers... it's easier